# Check for the pipe symbol with Regex

Tags: php, regex

The pipe symbol **`|`** is used in Regular Expression as a sort of 'either' statement, far as I know. Either this, either that, or that, or that, etc...

However, I wish to check a string with a regular expression, for the presence of this symbol. I've tried escaping it, but that doesn't seem to work.

How do I do this, especially if I'm already checking for a number of symbols to be present, like `#`, `&`, `@`, etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ cat 1933190.php

<?php
    echo preg_match("/\|/", "This is not a pipe.") . "\n";
    echo preg_match("/\|/", "The | the | this is a |.") . "\n";
?>
```

Output:

```
$ php 1933190.php
0
1
```

Answer (score 14):

Escaping that character is the right way. But make sure that you escape the escape characters in your string declaration as well:

```
"\\|"
'\\|'
```

Another way would be to use a character class (`[|]`) since in there you only have the characters `]`,  `^` (only at the start), `-`, the escape character `\` itself and the delimiter that have a special meaning and thus need to be escaped if meant to be expressed as plain characters.

Comment: And the caret character ^ only has special meaning if it is the first character in a character class, i.e. [^|] and [|^] will behave differently.